# Wordpress, разный header на страницах

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

Всем доброго дня! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть на мой взгляд весьма тривиальная задача) 
Есть сайт с 4 страницами. На каждой странице в хедере меняется текст. Я вывел в админку в меню, блок Хедер сайта. Создал запись, на всех страницах появился одинаковый хедер. Теперь мне нужно что бы текст был разный, я создаю новый хедер, он естественно отображается на той же странице, как сделать так что бы на нужной странице отображался нужный хедер ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почитайте https://codex.wordpress.org/Иерархия_шаблонов

Comment: Использовать нормальные темы или разбираться с тем, что ты купил (украл?). Никаких "шапок сайта" в ВП нет.

Comment: Я ни чего не покупал и не крал, я использую стандартный функционал ВП, просто пытаюсь в нем разобраться. Как создать подобный пункт, думаю вы, как специалист, знаете ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо воспользоваться советами выше, либо если хочешь иметь возможность в дальнейшем менять хедер на каждой странице через админку, то используй   acf и выводи в хедере значения соответствующих полей через get_field

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге пришлось воспользоваться полями, так как клиенту нужно на каждой странице менять контент. Думал просто обойтись без них, но скорого решения к сожалению не смогу найти. Спасибо за помощь !

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте себе несколько шаблонов с различным содержимым и используйте в нужных страницах. Юзайте функцию `get_template_part( 'theme/file' );` Где **theme** - папка с активной темой, а **file** - имя файла с шаблоном. Вызывайте нужный файл по id страницы. Пример кода:

```
$id = get_the_ID();
if ($id == 5) {
    get_template_part( 'theme/file0' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'theme/file1' );
}
```

Надеюсь как узнавать id страницы объяснять не нужно.

Comment: Вам спасибо, этот функционал использовал для шаблонов контента на страницах )

Answer (score 1):

Использовать стандартные функции WordPress
get_header() для основной шапки, которая определена, как header.php, а для кастомной get_header(‘custom’) код добавляешь в header-custom.php